# docker-compose build in background?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have to setup a new system where I copied 50 Apps which should be built with `docker-compose build`. This compose file is just there to build the images, the images/containers get spin up from other file. So my questions is:

`docker-compose build -d` does not work unfortunately.

[https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/#:~:text=The%20docker%2Dcompose%20up%20command,background%20and%20leaves%20them%20running](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/#:%7E:text=The%20docker%2Dcompose%20up%20command,background%20and%20leaves%20them%20running).

Is there any way to run that build progress in detached mode or use a workaround? This process might take like 20 hours and if I am idle for long enough I will get disconnected and the build process stops

Answer (score 4):

A workaround could be to make use of:

```
nohup docker-compose build &
```

`&` will allow the command to run in the background.

Prefixing `nohup` will prevent the command from being aborted when you exit the shell. It won't accept any input, but will write all output to `nohup.out` and places it in your current directory.

If you do not wish to receive any output, you can write the output to `/dev/null`:

```
nohup docker-compose build >& /dev/null &
```

Comment: can you explain that? I get a strange message when trying this: administrator@xxx:~/appcollection$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

Comment: I've updated my answer about how `nohup` handles output.